# Pandas: simple 'join' not working?

Tags: pandas

I like to think I'm not an idiot, but maybe I'm wrong. Can anyone explain to me why this isn't working? I can achieve the desired results using 'merge'. But I eventually need to join multiple `pandas` `DataFrames` so I need to get this method working.

```
In [2]: left = pandas.DataFrame({'ST_NAME': ['Oregon', 'Nebraska'], 'value': [4.685, 2.491]})

In [3]: right = pandas.DataFrame({'ST_NAME': ['Oregon', 'Nebraska'], 'value2': [6.218, 0.001]})

In [4]: left.join(right, on='ST_NAME', lsuffix='_left', rsuffix='_right')
Out[4]: 
  ST_NAME_left  value ST_NAME_right  value2
0       Oregon  4.685           NaN     NaN
1     Nebraska  2.491           NaN     NaN
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try using [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-joining-merging):

```
In [14]: right
Out[14]: 
    ST_NAME  value2
0    Oregon   6.218
1  Nebraska   0.001

In [15]: merge(left, right)
Out[15]: 
    ST_NAME  value  value2
0  Nebraska  2.491   0.001
1    Oregon  4.685   6.218

In [18]: merge(left, right, on='ST_NAME', sort=False)
Out[18]: 
    ST_NAME  value  value2
0    Oregon  4.685   6.218
1  Nebraska  2.491   0.001
```

`DataFrame.join` is a bit of legacy method and apparently doesn't do column-on-column joins (originally it did index on column using the on parameter, hence the "legacy" designation).

Comment: Interesting. So it looks like in order to get what I want I'll have to perform successive merges, since `merge` only take two DataFrames?

Comment: I had the same problem and found this answer.  It's correct.  From the 0.16.2 docs: <snip>The related DataFrame.join method, uses merge internally for the index-on-index and index-on-column(s) joins, but joins on indexes by default rather than trying to join on common columns (the default behavior for merge).</snip>

Answer (score 4):

I can confirm, Pandas join method is faulty. In my case both keys were long strings (18 characters) and result was as if pandas was only matching first couple of characters. Merge function is working properly. Please do not use join function, it should be really removed from available methods, otherwise it can mess it up big time.

Comment: Can second this, as of July 2022, the join method is still faulty. Had to check this answer for a sanity check.

It should either be removed or corrected. Anyone with a SQL background will be directed towards the join method the second they look it up, which might turn out to be a mistake down the line.

Comment: Second this as well as of May 2023. A simple inner join yields an empty dataframe where there should have been matches using 'on=key'. Substitute with .merge() worked immediately.